# recursive sum plus product in r

Tags: r

I have a data frame in R that consists of two (numeric) columns, say A and B. I would like to constructor the column consisting of the elements

```
  A1+B1
 (A1+B1)*A2+B2
((A1+B1)*A2+B2)*A3+B3
  ...
```

This probably is an easy one-liner, but I don't see it.

Edit: deleted the word vectorized from the title, since I'm basically just interested in any elegant solution (the dumb ones I can do myself). In F# - which I'm more familiar with - this would be something like (assuming the elements would be in a list as tuples, which would be more idiomatic):

```
ABlist |> List.fold (fun acc (a,b) -> acc*a+b) 1
```

Which is still something very short and clear. I'm dragging this up, because I'm an R noob and unfamiliar with it, but I have read somewhere that it's a functional language, so I would guess a solution in terms of a fold over a data-frame would exist?

Comment: Ignoring your ambiguous use of parentheses, `cumprod(A + B)`?

Comment: I'll check. If that doesn't first add element wise and then computes the cumulative product from the added vector, it might be right. Why are my parentheses ambiguous?

Comment: I was sort of assuming that you _meant_ (A1+B1) * (A2+B2), but if not, then what you're describing might not be vectorizable.

Comment: It should be `((A1+B1)*A2+B2)*A3+B3`, right?

Comment: Eh yes, of course! Thanks for spotting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a different answer driven by the failure of Bram's effort at using Reduce. It builds a list that has the A;B pairs and then sets the intial value for the accumulator to 1 so that the first multiplication doesn't get zeroed out:

```
abList <- mapply(c, A,B, SIMPLIFY=FALSE)  # keeps as a list
Reduce( function(acc,x) {acc*x[1]+x[2]},
         abList,init=c(1,0),
         accumulate=TRUE)[-1]             # removes the initialization value
#--------
[[1]]
[1] 4 3

[[2]]
[1] 10  8

[[3]]
[1] 31 25

[[4]]
[1] 128 104

[[5]]
[1] 645 525
```

Might take some further work with `s/lapply( ..., "[", 1)` to pull out the accumulator

```
> sapply( Reduce( function(acc,x) {acc*x[1]+x[2]},
+         abList,init=c(1,0),
+         accumulate=TRUE)[-1], "[", 1)
[1]   4  10  31 128 645
```

Comment: Just set `init = 1` and you'll get a scalar output. The part of `Reduce`'s doc describing `init` as `an R object of the same kind as the elements of x` is not really accurate.

Comment: Huh, that's rather interesting. So what are those second list items, anyway?

Comment: It's because `length(acc*x[1]+x[2])` is equal to `length(acc)`. If you init `acc` to `c(1, 0)` you will always get an output of length 2.

Comment: In the mean-time I figured it out myself (before seeing this answer), I basically found the same thing as you have now (see my edited answer). The preprocessing does make the solution a bit less elegant, though it's still not bad. Marking this as the answer, as it is R only, performant enough for my case and because I like functional programming :). everybody thanks for their help.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, turns out I was too lazy, I figured it out myself (note: before that there was a good answer using Rcpp already, but I can't use that at work). Basically just a translation to R of what I wrote in my edit on how I would do this in F#:

```
a <- c(1,2,3)
b <- c(4,5,6)
abList <- list(a,b)
Reduce( function(acc,x) {acc*x[[1]]+x[[2]]},
        abList,
        accumulate=TRUE)
```

Does the trick. Edit: as per the comment below, it actually doesn't do the trick. If one build abList by

```
abList <- apply(rbind(a,b),2,as.pairlist)
```

and then folds by:

```
Reduce(function(acc,x) {(acc*x[[1]])+x[[2]]},abList,1,accumulate=TRUE)
```

One gets the right answer (with a 1 prepended because that's the intial value for the accumulator)

Comment: I'm not getting the correct results with this (although it does look good). The first element should be 1+4 but the accumulator is 9.

Comment: You are correct, something is fishy. Let me try to fix it, because from the description of Reduce, this should work (though again, I'm an R noob)

Comment: Note that `Reduce` is not the same as `mapply`. To use Reduce, I think you would need to build your abList differently so that c(1,4) is the first element,  c(2,5) the second ... .

Answer (score 1):

This is relatively straightforward in Rcpp, which won't have the performance problems you would see if you tried to implement this with loops in R.

```
library(Rcpp)
sum.prod <- cppFunction(
"NumericVector sum_prod(NumericVector x, NumericVector y) {
  NumericVector result(x.size());
  result[0] = x[0] + y[0];
  for (int i=1; i < x.size(); ++i) result[i] = result[i-1]*x[i] + y[i];
  return result;
}")
sum.prod(c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), c(3, 2, 1, 4, 5))
# [1]   4  10  31 128 645
```

I've found Rcpp to be the simplest way to speed up hard-to-vectorize computations.

Comment: This probably works. I'll check at home, because at my PC at work, I'm not allowed to install the tools or packages I will need to compile the code above. If an native R answer shows up, I'll probably select that one as the right one, if not I'll flag this one as the answer after testing at home

Answer (score 1):

```
X = 1; for ( i in seq(length(A) ) ) { X= B[i]+A[i]*X; print(X) }
[1] 4
[1] 10
[1] 31
[1] 128
[1] 645
```

If you want to accumulate rather than reprot:

```
 X = 1; for ( i in seq(length(A) ) ) { X[1+i]= B[i]+A[i]*X[i] }; X[-1]
#[1]   4  10  31 128 645
```

Will be ploddingly slow compared to the Rcpp solution, but if you need to do the compilation step on the fly it's only when the lengths are more than 1000 that you might even notice the difference:

```
> A <- sample(1:10000, 1000);  B <- sample(1:10000, 1000)
> system.time( {X = 1; for ( i in seq(length(A) ) ) { X[1+i]= B[i]+A[i]*X[i] }; X[-1]})
   user  system elapsed 
  0.014   0.002   0.017 
> library(Rcpp)
> system.time( {sum.prod <- cppFunction(
+ "NumericVector sum_prod(NumericVector x, NumericVector y) {
+   NumericVector result(x.size());
+   result[0] = x[0] + y[0];
+   for (int i=1; i < x.size(); ++i) result[i] = result[i-1]*x[i] + y[i];
+   return result;
+ }")
+ sum.prod(A,B) } )
   user  system elapsed 
  0.012   0.002   0.014
```